# how to iterate through array inside array

Tags: c#, arrays

So i have something like this:

```
[Serializable]
class Class1
{   
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float Height;
    public enumEnumType EnumType;
}

private Class1Values[] Class1Types;

[Serializable]
class Class2
{   
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float Height;
    public Class1Values[] Class1Values;
  
}

[SerializeField]
private Class2Values[] Class2Types;
```

And I need to iterate over these arrays in such a way that for a certain height in class 2, certain heights of class 1 are displayed.
Something like:

```
if Class2Types.Height == 10
    if Class2Types.Class1Values.Height == 10:
        do something
    if Class2Types.Class1Values.Height == 5:
        do something else
if Class2Types.Height == 5
    if Class2Types.Class1Values.Height == 10:
        do something
    if Class2Types.Class1Values.Height == 5:
        do something else
```

I will be grateful if you tell me how to do it

Comment: what have you tried so far? for a nested array in most cases you simply need a nested loop, so most likely a foreach in a foreach.

Comment: Huh? `Class2Types.Height == 10` and `Class2Types.Height == 5` have the same logic. Are you sure need different evaluations?

Comment: @mikus im making world generation using 2 noises Elevation(class2) and Moisture(class1). For every elevation height i wanna choose moisure height and place tile

Comment: @MetroSmurf  im making world generation using 2 noises Elevation(class2) and Moisture(class1). For every elevation height i wanna choose moisure height and place tile

Answer (score 0):

You may need a loop to achieve this.

as per `mikus` comment `for a nested array in most cases you simply need a nested loop, so most likely a foreach in a foreach`.

below is sample nested foreach loop:

```
        foreach (var class2 in Class2Types)
        {
            if (class2.Height == 10)
            {
                foreach (var class1 in class2.Class1Values)
                {
                    if (class1.Height == 10)
                    {
                        // do something
                    }
                    else if (class1.Height == 5)
                    {
                        // do something
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (class2.Height == 5)
            {
                foreach (var class1 in class2.Class1Values)
                {
                    if (class1.Height == 10)
                    {
                        // do something
                    }
                    else if (class1.Height == 5)
                    {
                        // do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```